# How to programmatically add an event to a page using Graph API?

Tags: facebook, events, http, facebook-graph-api, access-token

Is it possible to programmatically add an event to a page using Facebook Graph API?
If yes, what HTTP request shall be made?

For example, Startup Weekend has [events on its Facebook page](http://www.facebook.com/startupweekend?v=app_2344061033).
These events can be added using [Graph API Event object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Creating event with the API is **no longer possible** in v2.0+. Check: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0

---

<strike>Yes it's possible.</strike>

Permissions:

1. `create_event`
2. `manage_pages`

So first you get the page id and its access token, through:

```
$facebook->api("/me/accounts");
```

The Result will be something like:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Page Name
                    [category] => Website
                    [id] => XXXXXX
                    [access_token] => XXXXX
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Page Name 2
                    [category] => Company
                    [id] => XXXXXXX
                    [access_token] => XXXXXXXX
                )
        )

)
```

**UPDATE:** To retrieve the page's `access_token` you could now call the `page` object directly like:

```
$page_info = $facebook->api("/PAGE_ID?fields=access_token");
```

The access token, if successful call, should be accessible: `$page_info['access_token']`

Now you get the Page ID and access token and use the `events` connection:

```
$nextWeek = time() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
$event_param = array(
    "access_token" => "XXXXXXXX",
    "name" => "My Page Event",
    "start_time" => $nextWeek,
    "location" => "Beirut"
);
$event_id = $facebook->api("/PAGE_ID/events", "POST", $event_param);
```

And you are done! :-)

Comment: this is exactly what I want! one more question, these access_token of pages expires?

Comment: @jsj: I didn't really check, but I *think* yes they expire.

Comment: @fjsj they expire if the admin of the page changes them, otherwise they don't

Comment: Seems like the API v1.0 was the only API that offered this, and now it's no longer responding (deprecated) :(  Even if you had a valid token.  v2.0+ don't seem to have any publish event capabilities!

Comment: @BadPirate, correct the `create_event` permissions is deprecated v2.0 onward, I will update my answer.