# How to Post on page's (fan page) wall as page not as its owner through my app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using c# (asp.net mvc) and want to post on page's wall as page, not as page's owner. (not as profile who owns it) through my page which is hosted some where else not on facebook.

How can i do this.

----------------edit--------------

This is my page
http://www.facebook.com/#!/pages/Rhino-Hub/135447799844908

i want to post on this page's wall as my page through my app rather then from this page owner's profile (which is also me).

Currently doing this to post a wall

1. Login on facebook
2. Switch acount to page by: Account Settings-->Use facebook as page--> Switch
3. Write something on wall

this way all subscribers would see an update.

I want to do this from my code.

---

**Answer I have accepted didn't solved my problem but ya it helped me a bit. I have accepted it as its the only answer this question has received.**

Comment: Do you want to post on people's walls anonymously?  Or do you want to post on people's walls without them having any ownership or control over the post?  Neither of these sounds like a good idea to me.  Both options would just be open doors for spammers to randomly post things on other people's walls without any accountability or recourse.

Comment: @Robert: i have updated question to explain more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use C#, but I'll give you the steps to get you started:

1. Grant the [`manage_pages`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) permission
2. <strike>Generate an Application `access_token`. Refer to this [document](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) (App Login section)</strike> (See **EDIT**)
3. Call:

   ```
   https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts
   ```
4. Use the page's `access_token` retrieved to publish to your page.

**EDIT:**
No need for the Application `access_token`, please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925705/how-to-programmatically-add-an-event-to-a-page-using-graph-api/4926393#4926393).

Comment: i implemented it using Javascript API. This thing "permission manage_pages" was really helpful. Waiting for some one else to reply on this too.

Comment: i implememnted it other way, but u r the only one who has made a reply, so option then to accept it.

Comment: @PraveenPrasad: While I do appreciate your accept, but if you already have the *complete* answer then I prefer you write it with some code (example) for others to learn from and after that accept your own answer!