# Facebook C# SDK - Post to wall

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook

I'm developing an asp.net MVC 3 Facebook app and I am trying to post a message to my wall. Here is my code:

```
FacebookWebClient client = new FacebookWebClient();

// Post to user's wall
var postparameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
postparameters["message"] = "Hello world!";
postparameters["name"] = "This is a name";
postparameters["link"] = "http://thisisalink.com;
postparameters["description"] = "This is a description";

var result = client.Post("/me/feed", postparameters);
```

I can get the access token using client.AccessToken, so I'm assuming I don't have to set it anywhere. This code produces no errors and for the result I get an ID. However, when I bring up my Facebook, I see nothing on my wall nor in my news feed. I'm not sure what I'm missing. I've looked at related questions here at StackOverflow, but I see no reports/questions similar to mine. I've also tried changing the code based on what I've seen in other posts, but to no avail. I also checked my Facebook account settings and I see my application listed with permission to post to my wall. I also tried posting a message to my wall via the Graph API explorer and I'm getting the same result. I get an ID in return, but when I check my Facebook account I see nothing. At been at this for a couple of days. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

[EDIT]
I wonder if something is wrong with my app generated access_token. Using this access_token, as I mentioned in my post, I get the same result using the Graph API explorer. An ID is returned, but no message on my wall. However, if I give the Graph API explorer permission to post to my wall and use its own generated access_token, I can successfully post a message using the explorer. Here's the FB login button code:

```
<div>
    <h1>Login using Facebook</h1>
    <p><fb:login-button perms="user_location, publish_stream, email"></fb:login-button></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try what's mentioned on the bottom in this link? http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/discussions/250353

Comment: Hi Major Byte. Thanks for the response. I tried that but unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I am experiencing the identical issue.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to add an additional parameter into your post parameters.

```
args["access_token"] = account.access_token;
```

this is the token of the specific page.

I wont repeat the code, follow here for example: [Post On Facebook Page As Page Not As Admin User Using Facebook C# SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231827/post-on-facebook-page-as-page-not-as-admin-user-using-facebook-c-sharp-sdk/5752447#5752447)

(second answer)

Answer (score 1):

Did you request right App permissions to Facebook in your action method?

Try: `[CanvasAuthorize(Permissions = "user_location, publish_stream, email")]`

Answer (score 0):

Did you append the `access_token` to the URL? See example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/social-network/FacebookHammockDemo.aspx). It's also documented [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) (see *Using the Access Token*).

```
/me/feed?access_token=<access_token>
```

Comment: Hi TheCodeKing, thanks for the response. Unfortunately, it did not work. I even tried posting without the Facebook C# SDK, but I'm seeing the same behavior. I get an ID in return, but see nothing on my wall. And then to make matters even more confusing for me, I used the Graph API Explorer to post to my wall using the same access token that I use in my app, and same behavior...ID, but nothing on the wall. Then, using the access token generated by the Graph API Explorer, I tried posting the same exact message, and I got a "duplicate message" error. But still nothing on my wall.

Comment: The app will need the stream_publish permission for the user. Have you checked that? Also access tokens recently changed for OAuth 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

with one small change, your code works fine for me. you have to pass the users auth token into the constructor like this...

```
var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

// Post to user's wall
var postparameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
postparameters["message"] = "Hello world!";
postparameters["name"] = "This is a name";
postparameters["link"] = "http://thisisalink.com;
postparameters["description"] = "This is a description";

var result = client.Post("/me/feed", postparameters);
```

this method works for me, although i am not sure which facebook sdk you are using.
i'm using http://facebooksdk.net/ its quite good so if you're not using it i would recommend it