# Why can't I add an event as a page?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to add an event to a page in the name of the page. I'm the admin of the page and I found a lot of stuff to the topic, but, no matter what I do, it ends in the PHP Exception:

> Uncaught Exception: You must be an admin of the specified page to perform the requested action.

I can add events with my app in my own profile. So, I think the problem is the Access Token. I tried several ways, but to me the best way seems to be:

1. Open the Graph API Explorer
2. Select my Application
3. Request a new access code with permissions manage_pages, publish_actions, publish_stream, create_event
4. Request /me/accounts
5. Get the access_token from the page I want to post to and use it in my script

My test script, that works in my own profile:

```
require 'src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $APPLICATION_ID,
  'secret' => $APPLICATION_SECRET,
  'cookie'     => false,
  'fileUpload' => true
));

$event_id = 0;
$event_name = "New Event API Test Event";
$event_start = '2013-12-04';
$event_privacy = "OPEN";

$ret_obj = $facebook->api('/'.$page_id.'/events?access_token='.$access_token, 'POST', 
array(
   'name' => $event_name,
   'start_time' => $event_start,
   'privacy_type' => $event_privacy,
   'location_id' => $location_id
));

if(isset($ret_obj['id'])) {
  echo 'Event with added. ID: ' . $ret_obj['id'];
} else {
  echo 'Couldn\'t create event';
}
```

What I did wrong?

Comment: So where does `$access_token` come from in that code? Have you [debugged it](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to see if it’s actually a valid access token for that page?

Comment: @CBroe Sorry, the $access_token and the other variables used are on top of the code. I validated the code with https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug and it's vali. The profile ID is the same as the $page_id in my test code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a **page** access token.

> **Page Access Token** – These access tokens are similar to user access
>   tokens, except that they provide permission to APIs that read, write
>   or modify the data belonging to a Facebook Page. To obtain a page
>   access token you need to start by obtaining a user access token and
>   asking for the **`manage_pages` permission**. Once you have the user access
>   token you then get the page access token via the Graph API.
>
> *Doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/*

Then use `GET /me/accounts` to get the access token associated to your page.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in [How to programmatically add an event to a page using Graph API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925705/how-to-programmatically-add-an-event-to-a-page-using-graph-api). I had to add the access_token direct into the event array and everything works as expected:

```
    $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/'.$page_id.'/events', 'POST',
      array(
        'access_token' => $access_token,
        'name' => $event_name,
        'start_time' => $event_start,
        'privacy_type' => $event_privacy,
        'location_id' => $location_id
     ));
```

Thanks for the help!